# Mapbox React Native Turn By Turn Navigation ANR Problem

Tags: java, android, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-android

React Native version is 59.5

We use https://github.com/SRHealth/react-native-mapbox-navigation but this example renders mapboxnavigationview different view. We don't want to works like that.

We are using Mapbox Navigation on our application. iOS works fine but Android has ANR Problem.

Mapbox iOS has not any problem. It works like a charm.

Android is freezing but not all times.

Logcat;

```
10-23 12:03:40.907  2104  2239 E ActivityManager: ANR in com.mybundle (com.mybunle/.MainActivity)
10-23 12:03:40.907  2104  2239 E ActivityManager: PID: 25847
10-23 12:03:40.907  2104  2239 E ActivityManager: Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 2.  Wait queue head age: 48808.3ms.)
10-23 12:03:40.907  2104  2239 E ActivityManager: Load: 9.4 / 9.37 / 8.86
10-23 12:03:40.907  2104  2239 E ActivityManager: CPU usage from 0ms to 8134ms later (2019-10-23 12:03:32.741 to 2019-10-23 12:03:40.876):
```

My native component which is mapboxnavigationview;

```
package com.mybundle.Mapbox;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.location.Location;
// import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
// import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineCallback;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineResult;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsResponse;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraPosition;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdate;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLngBounds;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.RenderMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.camera.DynamicCamera;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.camera.NavigationCamera;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.camera.NavigationCameraUpdate;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.instruction.InstructionView;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.map.NavigationMapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.voice.NavigationSpeechPlayer;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.voice.SpeechAnnouncement;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.voice.SpeechPlayerProvider;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.voice.VoiceInstructionLoader;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.milestone.Milestone;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.milestone.MilestoneEventListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.milestone.VoiceInstructionMilestone;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.MapboxNavigation;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationRoute;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.offroute.OffRouteListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.routeprogress.ProgressChangeListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.routeprogress.RouteProgress;
import com.mybundle.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import okhttp3.Cache;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import timber.log.Timber;

public class MapboxNavigationView extends LinearLayout implements OnMapReadyCallback,
  MapboxMap.OnMapLongClickListener, ProgressChangeListener, MilestoneEventListener, OffRouteListener {


    private static final int FIRST = 0;
    private static final int ONE_HUNDRED_MILLISECONDS = 100;
    private static final int BOTTOMSHEET_PADDING_MULTIPLIER = 4;
    private static final int TWO_SECONDS_IN_MILLISECONDS = 2000;
    private static final double BEARING_TOLERANCE = 90d;
    private static final String LONG_PRESS_MAP_MESSAGE = "Long press the map to select a destination.";
    private static final String SEARCHING_FOR_GPS_MESSAGE = "Searching for GPS...";
    private static final String COMPONENT_NAVIGATION_INSTRUCTION_CACHE = "component-navigation-instruction-cache";
    private static final long TEN_MEGABYTE_CACHE_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    private static final int ZERO_PADDING = 0;
    private static final double DEFAULT_ZOOM = 12.0;
    private static final double DEFAULT_TILT = 0d;
    private static final double DEFAULT_BEARING = 0d;
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000;
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 500;


    private Context context;
    private final MapboxNavigationViewLocationCallback callback = new MapboxNavigationViewLocationCallback(this);
    private LocationEngine locationEngine;
    private MapboxNavigation navigation;
    private NavigationSpeechPlayer speechPlayer;
    private NavigationMapboxMap navigationMap;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private DirectionsRoute route;
    private Point destination = null;

    private InstructionView instructionView;
    private MapView mapView;

    private boolean mapLoaded = false;

    public MapboxNavigationView(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);

        this.context = reactContext;
        context.setTheme(R.style.CustomInstructionView);

        inflate(context, R.layout.navigation_view, this);

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        instructionView = findViewById(R.id.instructionView);
        mapView.onCreate(null);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        mapboxMap.setStyle(new Style.Builder().fromUri(context.getString(R.string.navigation_guidance_day)), style -> {
            navigationMap = new NavigationMapboxMap(mapView, mapboxMap);

            // For Location updates
            initializeLocationEngine();

            // For navigation logic / processing
            initializeNavigation(mapboxMap);
            navigationMap.updateCameraTrackingMode(NavigationCamera.NAVIGATION_TRACKING_MODE_NONE);
            navigationMap.updateLocationLayerRenderMode(RenderMode.GPS);

            // For voice instructions
            initializeSpeechPlayer();
            mapLoaded = true;
            if(destination != null)
            {
                navigateToDestination(destination);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
        // Only reverse geocode while we are not in navigation
        return false;
    }
    /*
     * Navigation listeners
     */

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        navigation.onDestroy();
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }


    @Override
    public void onProgressChange(Location location, RouteProgress routeProgress) {
        // Cache "snapped" Locations for re-route Directions API requests
        updateLocation(location);

        // Update InstructionView data from RouteProgress
        instructionView.updateDistanceWith(routeProgress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMilestoneEvent(RouteProgress routeProgress, String instruction, Milestone milestone) {
        playAnnouncement(milestone);

        // Update InstructionView banner instructions
        instructionView.updateBannerInstructionsWith(milestone);
    }

    @Override
    public void userOffRoute(Location location) {
        calculateRouteWith(destination, true);
    }

    /*
     * Activity lifecycle methods
     */


    void checkFirstUpdate(Location location) {
        if (lastLocation == null) {
            lastLocation = location;
            moveCameraTo(location);
            if(destination != null ) navigateToDestination(destination);
            // Allow navigationMap clicks now that we have the current Location
        }
    }

    void updateLocation(Location location) {
        lastLocation = location;
        navigationMap.updateLocation(location);
    }

    private void initializeSpeechPlayer() {
        String english = "en";
        String lng = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
        if(lng.equals("Deutsch")){
            english = "de";
        }
        Cache cache = new Cache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), COMPONENT_NAVIGATION_INSTRUCTION_CACHE),
                TEN_MEGABYTE_CACHE_SIZE);
        VoiceInstructionLoader voiceInstructionLoader = new VoiceInstructionLoader(context,
                Mapbox.getAccessToken(), cache);
        SpeechPlayerProvider speechPlayerProvider = new SpeechPlayerProvider(context, english, true,
                voiceInstructionLoader);
        speechPlayer = new NavigationSpeechPlayer(speechPlayerProvider);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void initializeLocationEngine() {
        locationEngine = LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(context);
        LocationEngineRequest request = buildEngineRequest();
        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, callback, null);

    }

    private void initializeNavigation(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        navigation = new MapboxNavigation(context, Mapbox.getAccessToken());
        navigation.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);
        navigation.setCameraEngine(new DynamicCamera(mapboxMap));
        navigation.addProgressChangeListener(this);
        navigation.addMilestoneEventListener(this);
        navigation.addOffRouteListener(this);
        navigationMap.addProgressChangeListener(navigation);
    }


    private void playAnnouncement(Milestone milestone) {
        if (milestone instanceof VoiceInstructionMilestone) {
            SpeechAnnouncement announcement = SpeechAnnouncement.builder()
                    .voiceInstructionMilestone((VoiceInstructionMilestone) milestone)
                    .build();
            speechPlayer.play(announcement);
        }
    }

    private void moveCameraTo(Location location) {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = buildCameraPositionFrom(location, location.getBearing());
        navigationMap.retrieveMap().animateCamera(
                CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), TWO_SECONDS_IN_MILLISECONDS
        );
    }

    private void moveCameraToInclude(Point destination) {
        LatLng origin = new LatLng(lastLocation);
        LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                .include(origin)
                .include(new LatLng(destination.latitude(), destination.longitude()))
                .build();
        Resources resources = getResources();
        int routeCameraPadding = (int) resources.getDimension(R.dimen.component_navigation_route_camera_padding);
        int[] padding = {routeCameraPadding, routeCameraPadding, routeCameraPadding, routeCameraPadding};
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = navigationMap.retrieveMap().getCameraForLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        navigationMap.retrieveMap().animateCamera(
                CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), TWO_SECONDS_IN_MILLISECONDS
        );
    }

    private void moveCameraOverhead() {
        if (lastLocation == null) {
            return;
        }
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = buildCameraPositionFrom(lastLocation, DEFAULT_BEARING);
        navigationMap.retrieveMap().animateCamera(
                CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), TWO_SECONDS_IN_MILLISECONDS
        );
    }

    @Nullable
    private CameraUpdate cameraOverheadUpdate() {
        if (lastLocation == null) {
            return null;
        }
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = buildCameraPositionFrom(lastLocation, DEFAULT_BEARING);
        return CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
    }

    @NonNull
    private CameraPosition buildCameraPositionFrom(Location location, double bearing) {
        return new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .zoom(DEFAULT_ZOOM)
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                .bearing(bearing)
                .tilt(DEFAULT_TILT)
                .build();
    }

    private void adjustMapPaddingForNavigation() {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        int mapViewHeight = mapView.getHeight();
        int bottomSheetHeight = (int) resources.getDimension(R.dimen.component_navigation_bottomsheet_height);
        int topPadding = mapViewHeight - (bottomSheetHeight * BOTTOMSHEET_PADDING_MULTIPLIER);
        navigationMap.retrieveMap().setPadding(ZERO_PADDING, topPadding, ZERO_PADDING, ZERO_PADDING);
    }

    private void resetMapAfterNavigation() {
        navigationMap.removeRoute();
        navigationMap.clearMarkers();
        navigation.stopNavigation();
        moveCameraOverhead();
    }

    private void removeLocationEngineListener() {
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates(callback);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void addLocationEngineListener() {
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            LocationEngineRequest request = buildEngineRequest();
            locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, callback, null);
        }
    }

    private void calculateRouteWith(Point destination, boolean isOffRoute) {
        Point origin = Point.fromLngLat(lastLocation.getLongitude(), lastLocation.getLatitude());
        Double bearing = Float.valueOf(lastLocation.getBearing()).doubleValue();
        NavigationRoute.builder(context)
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(origin, bearing, BEARING_TOLERANCE)
                .destination(destination)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<DirectionsResponse> call, @NonNull Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                        handleRoute(response, isOffRoute);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<DirectionsResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable throwable) {
                        Timber.e("fuck;");
                    }
                });
    }


    public void navigateToDestination(Point destination)
    {
        this.destination = destination;
        if(mapLoaded && lastLocation != null) calculateRouteWith(destination, false);
    }

    private void quickStartNavigation() {
        // Transition to navigation state


        // Show the InstructionView
        instructionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        adjustMapPaddingForNavigation();
        // Updates camera with last location before starting navigating,
        // making sure the route information is updated
        // by the time the initial camera tracking animation is fired off
        // Alternatively, NavigationMapboxMap#startCamera could be used here,
        // centering the map camera to the beginning of the provided route
        navigationMap.resumeCamera(lastLocation);
        navigation.startNavigation(route);

        // Location updates will be received from ProgressChangeListener
        removeLocationEngineListener();

        // TODO remove example usage
        navigationMap.resetCameraPositionWith(NavigationCamera.NAVIGATION_TRACKING_MODE_GPS);
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = cameraOverheadUpdate();
        if (cameraUpdate != null) {
            NavigationCameraUpdate navUpdate = new NavigationCameraUpdate(cameraUpdate);
            navigationMap.retrieveCamera().update(navUpdate);
        }
    }

    private void handleRoute(Response<DirectionsResponse> response, boolean isOffRoute) {
        List<DirectionsRoute> routes = response.body().routes();
        if (!routes.isEmpty()) {
            route = routes.get(FIRST);
            navigationMap.drawRoute(route);
            if (isOffRoute) {
                navigation.startNavigation(route);
            }else quickStartNavigation();
        }
    }


    @NonNull
    private LocationEngineRequest buildEngineRequest() {
        return new LocationEngineRequest.Builder(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .setPriority(LocationEngineRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
    }


    private static class MapboxNavigationViewLocationCallback implements LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult> {

        private final WeakReference<MapboxNavigationView> activityWeakReference;

        MapboxNavigationViewLocationCallback(MapboxNavigationView activity) {
            this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationEngineResult result) {
            MapboxNavigationView activity = activityWeakReference.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                Location location = result.getLastLocation();
                if (location == null) {
                    return;
                }
                activity.checkFirstUpdate(location);
                activity.updateLocation(location);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

        }
    }
}
```

I did not find any solution.